# Are there multiple meanings to "clone" as in "clone a gene"?

Tags: genetics

I originally thought that cloning a gene meant to put it into bacteria and have them express it. But sometimes I see it used and it seems like it's just a synonym for "identify the sequence and/or location of". So what does "clone a gene" really mean"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to clone a gene?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41224/what-does-it-mean-to-clone-a-gene)

Answer (score 1):

"Cloning a gene" also just means making tons of copies of it, like in PCR, so you can sequence it

Comment: isn't making 'tons of copies' not regarded as 'amplification'?

Comment: I think it can be referred to as either amplification or cloning